# .NET project not able to connect to Docker container in WSL2 via localhost from the host OS

Tags: windows, docker, .net-5, wsl-2

I am not using Docker Desktop, I only installed the CLI on Ubuntu, on WSL2. I also downloaded RabbitMQ image and successfully connected to localhost:15672 from my browser on Windows host.

But, when it came to the .NET project, it wasn't possible. This is the connection string:

> "host=localhost:5672;publisherConfirms=true;timeout=25;username=nerdstore;password=!abcd1234!"

One solution was to use eth0's inet IP address from within Ubuntu, but I have many projects using this connection, it is a pain to modify it every day, at least.

> "host=123.45.67.890:5672;publisherConfirms=true;timeout=25;username=nerdstore;password=!abcd1234!"

Why is that I am able to connect to the container via browser but not form the .NET project and how could I manage to do it?

Comment: Is the .NET project running on the host OS, or in a container?

Comment: @DavidMaze, the project is running on the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Ubuntu IP `123.45.67.890` into hosts file with your custom hostname `wsl2.ubuntu` by below command.

Make sure you run PowerShell as administrator.

```
Add-Content -Path $env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Value "`n123.45.67.890`twsl2.ubuntu" -Force
```

Then you connection would be like this

> "host=wsl2.ubuntu:5672;publisherConfirms=true;timeout=25;username=nerdstore;password=!abcd1234!"

Comment: It helped. Like this, I need to change the IP in one place only. But, is there a way to access "localhost" from the .NET project like it is possible from the browser?